# How to do uniq -d without presorting (or something similar)

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, duplicates, uniq

I am aware that I can remove duplicated lines without presorting, for example:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' file
```

However, my goal is to only print lines which are duplicated and only once.  If it were not for the presorting problem

```
sort | uniq -d
```

would be perfect.  BUT the order is of great importance to me.  Is there a way to do this with awk, grep or something similar?

I am looking for a one liner which does not require writing a script if possible.

Comment: Are you claiming `sort | uniq -d` doesn't preserve the order? It does for me on `(GNU coreutils) 8.4`

Comment: @Inian I think he meant that he would use `uniq -d` if he did not have to sort it first..

Comment: @lewiatan exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the value of `x[$0]`:

```
awk 'x[$0]++ == 1' file.txt
```

The above will print a line when it's seen for the second time.

Or with prefixed `++`:

```
awk '++x[$0] == 2' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try simply removing `!` from your `awk` command.

```
bash-4.1$ cat /tmp/inp.txt 
abc
def
abc
xyz
def
hello

bash-4.1$ awk 'x[$0]++ == 1' /tmp/inp.txt 
abc
def
```

Hope this is what you expect!!