# Shell Script - How to merge two text files without repeating lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell

my case is apparently easy, but I couldn't do it in a simple way and I need it because the real files is very large.

So, I have two txt files and I would like to generate a new file containing the both content of the two without duplicating the lines. Something like that:

**file1.txt**

```
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101
192.168.0.102
```

**file2.txt**

```
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101
192.168.1.200
192.168.1.201
```

I would like to merge these files above and generate another one like this:

**result.txt**

```
192.168.0.100
192.168.0.101
192.168.0.102
192.168.1.200
192.168.1.201
```

Any simple sugestions?
Thank you

Comment: How large is "very large"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing the order is not an issue:

```
sort -u file1.txt file2.txt > result.txt
```

First this sorts the lines of both files (in memory), then it runs through them and outputs each unique line only once (`-u` flag).

Comment: Optimization if the files are already sorted like in OP's examples: `sort -mu file1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 2):

There's a semi-standard idiom in `awk` for removing duplicates:

```
awk '!a[$0]++ {print}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The array `a` counts occurrences of each line, but only prints a line the first time it is added (i.e., when `a[$0]` is 0 before it is incremented).

This is asymptotically faster than sorting the input (and preserves the input order), but requires more memory.

Comment: `sort` also needs to keep all lines into memory (at least once per unique line) so I'd expect memory usage to be similar.

Comment: `awk` is storing all the output, since any input line could have been seen arbitrarily long ago. `sort`, on the other hand, only has to remember each line until  the next new input line comes along, at which point that line replaces the line in memory.

Comment: Full disclosure, there is almost certainly a duplicate question, since I'm pretty sure I learned this trick from Stack Overflow. The closest I can find is a question that acknowledges this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38203260/1126841.

Comment: I usually see it with the `{print}` left out since that's the default action.

Comment: @chepner No, `sort` (without the `-m` flag) will need to read all lines into memory first before it can sort them. How else could it possibly know that it's safe to output a line? Another input line could come along that should have been sorted before that one. If you don't believe me, try `sort` without any arguments, type some lines, and observe how they are not echoed back until you hit Ctrl+D to end the input. That said, with `-u` there is no need for `sort` to keep multiple duplicates in memory, but neither does your `awk` solution.

Comment: `sort` uses disk-based algorithms, both to handle sorting files that cannot be fully stored in memory, as well as allowing you to limit how much memory it can use. `sort` of course needs to *read* all its input before it can start outputting, but that doesn't mean it actually keeps all the data in memory. `awk`, on the other hand, has no such optimization built-in (at least, none that I am aware of).

Comment: There is possibly a solution with grep to preserve the order. But what order is to be preserved? That depends on the order of the merged files.